# Powershell wget error: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: powershell, ssl, pip

I tried to run this command in powershell:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -Outfile ez_setup.py
```

But there is an error saying

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

What should I do to solve this error? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Check if you can open the URL in IE manually. Most likely you'll end up with something out of scope like "Your Internet access is blocked due to low funds", or connection timeout, or a 302 to blocking page, etc etc.

Comment: @Vesper That's unlikely. If you take a look at the duplicate, it explains Powershell's default TLS settings to be incompatible with the target site's offering.